Getting error in updating the Graph API version for creating worksheet
I have written some code for my project, where I'm creating the worksheet using the Graph API version 5.42 in Java.
Now I'm updating the version to the latest one, and it is not showing the below error for the respective code.
This code worked perfectly fine with the older API version, but it's breaking with the newer API version.
Error showing in the below code:
Cannot resolve method '.me()'
Cannot resolve symbol 'WorkbookWorksheetAddParameterSet'
Cannot resolve symbol 'GraphServiceException'
Code:
import com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.*;
import com.microsoft.graph.options.HeaderOption;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.WorkbookWorksheetRangeRequest;
private GraphServiceClient client;
public boolean createWorksheet(String worksheetName) {
        try {
            // API call to create new worksheet
            client.me()
                    .drive()
                    .root()
                    .itemWithPath(workbookPath)
                    .workbook()
                    .worksheets()
                    .add(
                            WorkbookWorksheetAddParameterSet.newBuilder()
                              .withName(Utils.encodeString(worksheetName))
                                    .build())
                    .buildRequest(workbookSessionIdHeader)
                    .post();
            setActiveSheetName(worksheetName);
            return true;
        } catch (GraphServiceException exception) {
            System.err.println("Graph service encountered an error: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

The entire code is breaking, I tried but didn't find any solutions
